# Consume SOAP API in MuleSoft using JAVA

Tags: mulesoft

I want to consume soap api from mulesoft using java.

I have WSDL file with authentication key. I want to consume the soap webservice from mulesoft  using java where I want to pass the payload, username, password and the url of the api and call the java static method from mulesoft.

Comment: Do you have an issue or a question? And why not use the web service consumer?

Comment: Ii am not familiar with mulesoft how to use it thats why I asked the question. Can u please help?

Comment: You didn't ask any questions. You stated some facts about something that you need to do. Have you tried something? Have you researched the topic? Do you still need to learn the basics? Note that you are expected to do effort on your own before asking here. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should learn about Mule (not to be confused with the company MuleSoft). Specifically about the Web Service Consumer and the Java Module and then ask a specific question if you have a specific issue.